# Aurelia and Open-Id-Connect plugin for IdentityServer

Tags: aurelia, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have implemented local [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts) using Quickstart sample and connected  [Aurelia-Opein-Id-Connect](https://github.com/aurelia-contrib/aurelia-open-id-connect-demos) to it. The setup works fine.

The question I have is:

1. When I run the Aurelia app as it is, its provide me with *(Claims) name and website*. But when I change open-id-connect-configuration-identity-server.ts and add "token" to `response_type: "id_token token"`, it does not provide me with my claims, which is name and website. Though now it provides me with an access_token.
2. How to use this access_token and use it to access web-api after successful login?

Please if anyone can share their experience on this.

Comment: You said you had an access token when you changed the `response_type` to `id_token token`, so that's question 2 answered. As for the first one, it's likely a configuration on your IdentityServer. In your client, try setting `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to `true`.

Comment: I modified the 2nd question little bit. My question is how I can use this access token to access web-api in Aurelia.
Your AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken to true answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `access_token` to make HTTP requests, you need to set it as a Bearer token on your request headers. This can be done in any way you'd like of course, a convenient way to do this is to write an `interceptor` that will append the header for every HTTP request you make.

The way you make an interceptor is by doing the following in `main.ts`:

```js
import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-fetch-client";

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  // Other configuration

  const httpClient = aurelia.container.get(HttpClient);

  httpClient.configure((config) => {
    config
      .withInterceptor({
        request(request) {
          const token = getToken(); // Implement your preferred way to do this
          if (token) {
            request.headers.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
          }
          return request;
        }
    });
  });

  // More configuration
}
```

This code will append the `access_token` that you retrieve using `getToken()` to any HTTP request you make.

---

*A* way to retrieve your token here is to store the token in a singleton class, that you then retrieve from the Aurelia container the same way you retrieve the `httpClient`:

```js
const currentUser = aurelia.container.get(CurrentUser);
```

However, this is entirely up to what you prefer.